# firebase PHP: create user

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security

I have data that I need to save into firebase from a user.  My Firebase schema is like..

```
{
   users: {
      1: {
         data..
```

Is it possible to create a new Firebase user in PHP so that I can use the generated user_id to save the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your questions. If you're trying to authenticate a client as a given user, you need to generate an authentication token, place it in the page, and have the client call auth() with that token. See the docs here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html

If you're merely trying to write some data into Firebase at the /users location from PHP, you can do so with the REST API:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html

Comment: Sorry Andrew, now that i re-read my question, it is badly written.  What i wanted to know is, can I use Simple email/password auth method to create a new user using PHP?

Comment: John - our Simple Login service is specifically designed for people that want to do auth without running their own server. Since you're using PHP already, you must have your own server, and I'd be surprised if you weren't already doing user authentication yourself. 

If you don't have your own user authentication on your own servers, why route user creation through your PHP code at all? Why not just have the clients talk directly to the Simple Login servers?

Comment: We are using the PHP server to parse incoming email.  Thanks for you answer, I was aware of using our own auth, but wanted to know if its possible.

Comment: I'd suggest then keeping track of user accounts yourself then and generating auth tokens on your own server.