# How to createUser using Firebase REST API?

Tags: firebase

In the front end Javascript library, you can call `createUser` to create a user and have it under "Registered Users" under Login & Auth in the dashboard. I would like to do the same in my backend using .Net so that it can record a new user. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

It is currently not possible to create a user through the Firebase REST API.

Related:

- [firebase PHP: create user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882744/firebase-php-create-user)
- [Create a Firebase using the REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703206/add-registered-users-to-firebase-with-the-rest-api)

Answer (score -1):

If someone looking for this and wanted to create user to Authenticate with PHP. You can read this: http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#create-a-user-with-email-and-password

:)

Comment: Link is down, please add more information to the answer