# Python/Firebase create authenticated user

Tags: python, firebase

So I was trying to implement some security rules, when I came across the **Login & Auth** tab in Firebase.
I am using the following third-party library: https://github.com/shariq/firebase-python, which supports some basic functions (just to put/get data in and from firebase).
Now the thing I wanted to do, is not only put users under the `/users/{id}` nodes, but to create authenticated users in the **Login & Auth** tab. I understand that the Firebase REST API does not support this operation? How would I go about this, using the request library? Is this even possible? (The idea then is to extend this one -> https://github.com/shariq/firebase-python)

Comment: It's currently not possible to create users through Firebase's REST API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027535/how-to-createuser-using-firebase-rest-api

Comment: I see. Is it possible to circumvent this, do it another way? Or are you saying it is not possible in any way right now. Excuse me for the questions, but i've been tasked to do this so i'd really like to know :-)